# What I'm missing on sending to WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm developing an application which interacts with bing ads api, here is endpoint description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-campaign-management-addadextensions

I'm sending this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v9" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <env:Header>
    <tns:UserName>API_project_test</tns:UserName>
    <tns:Password>***FILTERED***</tns:Password>
    <tns:DeveloperToken>***FILTERED***</tns:DeveloperToken>
    <tns:CustomerId>1147374</tns:CustomerId>
    <tns:CustomerAccountId>434383475</tns:CustomerAccountId>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:AddAdExtensionsRequest>
      <tns:AdExtensions xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tns:AdExtension>
          <tns:ForwardCompatibilityMap xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
          <tns:SiteLinks>
            <tns:SiteLink>
              <tns:DestnationUrl>http://sterkonix.cz</tns:DestnationUrl>
              <tns:DisplayText>Hello world</tns:DisplayText>
            </tns:SiteLink>
          </tns:SiteLinks>
        </tns:AdExtension>
      </tns:AdExtensions>
    </tns:AddAdExtensionsRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And I'm getting this kind of error:

```
SOAP response (status 500):
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</fau
ltcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Cannot create an abstract class.</faultstring><detail><ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLS
chema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/><Message>Cannot create an abstract class.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.nativeGetUninitializedObje
ct(RuntimeType type)&#xD;
   at ReadAdExtensionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)&#xD;
   at ReadArrayOfAdExtensionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)&#xD;
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] par
ameters, Boolean isRequest)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><Type>System.MemberAccessException</Type></ExceptionDetail></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

What do I need to send to prevent bingads wsdl from refusing my xml?

Comment: Either there's something wrong with your message, or there's a problem with the service.   Are you missing some required fields?  And BTW, you don't send messages to the WSDL, you send them to the service.  The WSDL is simply a definition of the service that clients can use to build the proxy.

Comment: Hey! I'm sending all required fields (as I think). ok, glad to know about wsdl